# Okta Session hand-over from desktop application to web application

Tags: session, cookies, authorization, okta

We have a desktop application that is used to upload content to a web application, both use Okta for authentication. Before uploading, the desktop application authenticates the user via Okta using an embedded browser control. Later in the workflow we want to open the user's default browser so he/she can start using the web application directly. At the moment the user will need to login a second time when their default browser opens.

We planned to implement a mechanism to generate a one-time key (transferable session token) that can be passed as a URL parameter when the browser is opened. For our application's own token we can achieve this but we also need to transfer the Okta session (cookie) and we have not found a way to transfer this from the desktop browser control to the standalone browser.

What options are available to achieve this?

Edit: it is acceptable if a new session is created for the standalone browser as long as the user identity stays the same and the user does not have to provide login details a second time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Okta does not have a way to transfer one active session to another as you describe.

However, if you have enough control over the organization's environment, you could simulate this behavior. For Okta organizations that use [IWA](https://support.okta.com/help/articles/Knowledge_Article/28101616-Configuring-Desktop-SSO#InstallingIWA) to authenticate users, you would get this sort of feature "automatically" (provided that the user's default browser supports Active Directory). Another way could be to configure your web application as a "SAML IdP" and have it "transfer a session" to Okta using a SAML Response and Okta's [Inbound SAML](https://support.okta.com/help/articles/Knowledge_Article/40561903-Configuring-Inbound-SAML) functionality.